# How do I install or upgrade macOS Ventura in my old MacBook Pro 13" (Early 2015)

Tags: macos

My current MacBook Pro was purchased on 2015 which has macOS Monterey Version 12.6.7. I have installed all the updates till date what machine recommends but I am not getting notification for Ventura. Why ? may be Ventura supports only Apple M1 & M2 family ?

I have no clue how to install macOs Ventura in my MacBook Pro (Early 2015) or update from macOS Monterey to Ventura

Answer (score 3):

You can see [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213264) from the Apple KB : the oldest compatible Macbook model eligible to the Ventura upgrade is the MBP 13/15" from 2017. Your hardware simply isn't supported.

Comment: Yes I reviewed that page already, thanks for sharing it anyhow. Do you know any other alternative ways ?

Comment: You can find [articles](https://www.macworld.com/article/672461/how-to-install-macos-on-unsupported-mac.html) promoting the use of [OpenCore Legacy Patcher](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/MODELS.html).  Never used personally.  Should you decide to try it, be sure to backup your data, and bear in mind it's probably a _use-at-your-own-risk_ kind of procedure.

Comment: @KannanMN, You should have stated in your original question that you had read the KB article about Ventura compatibility and that what you really want to know is how to install Ventura on unsupported hardware.